# Styling the AsyncFileUpload control

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have been trying to format the AsyncFileUpload control for a while now and i just can´t figure out a way of how to do it. I tried some method that are efective when styling the common input type and the ASP.NET Web Forms FileUpload control, like setting opacity to 0 and hiding the browse button on top of some other element, but none of those techniques seem to be working effectively on the AsyncFileUpload. Does any one have some kind of method to apply some styling to this control? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of this is what you are looking for but I hope it helps
http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/aspnet-flash-file-uploader-with-s3-support/